# how to use filter in a modal instance

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I used modal instance to open a modal with controller which is defined inside the main controller.

```
var helloControllers = angular.module('helloControllers', []);

helloControllers.controller('ScheduleUpdateCtrl', ['$scope','$routeParams', '$http','$modal',
function($scope,$routeParams, $http, $modal) {

/*--------lines of code-------------*/

$scope.setting=function(){
      var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'ScheduleSettings/ScheduleSettings.html',
          controller: ScheduleSettingsCtrl,

/*--- lines of code--------------*/

var ScheduleSettingsCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance,$filter,scheduleId,scheduleName,grouplist,devicelist,secondtime)
```

Now I need to use a filter for a listbox to exclude the items which is contained in another listbox

```
<select size=9 ng-model="deviceselected" ng-options="de as de.DEVICE_NAME for de in deviceAllList|exclude"></select>
<select size=9 ng-model="deviceavailable" ng-options="de as de.DEVICE_NAME for de in deviceList"></select>
```

Something like:

```
filter('exclude',function(){
return function(array){
    var out=[];
    alert('!');
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        alert(array[i].GROUP_ID);
        if(groupList.map(function(e) { return e.GROUP_NAME; }).indexOf(array[i].GROUP_NAME)==-1)
            out.push(array[i]);
    }
    return out;
};
```

But I don't know where to put these lines or use it in html. I'm clueless so helps with demo would be much appreciated.

---

More details

More questions:
Where should the filter definition belong to? I tried

```
 helloControllers.filter('exclude',function(){
```

How to test if the filter call is valid/undefined? I got this error.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: excludeFilterFilterProvider <- excludeFilterFilter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: It is as simple as we are using filter in some other html element.Same way with `|` you can apply filter here in `ng-options`

```
 <select size=9 ng-model="deviceselected" ng-options="de as de.DEVICE_NAME for de in deviceAllList | exclude"></select>
 <select size=9 ng-model="deviceavailable" ng-options="de as de.DEVICE_NAME for de in deviceList | exclude"></select>
```

Comment: Yes, I did try this but the list box was blank. Is there any way to test if the filter is valid/undefined?

Comment: I got this error
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: excludeFilterFilterProvider <- excludeFilterFilter

Comment: Did you register filter in you application module ?

Comment: I did this helloControllers.filter('exclude',function(){. But I am not sure if this is valid or not. Please check my edited post.

Comment: @dtxd As you already wrote alert in the filter so once filter will call it will alert you. and yes it is valid.

Comment: @dtxd Welcome, It's my pleasure to help you.Do upvote and accept answer if it's help you to solve your problem.